# Query with records that the count of a second query count equal 0

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to use a DB that will keep track of our ECNs here at work.
So I have a table for the ECN entries.
[ECN Entries Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvHMh.png)
When the use clicks on the hyperlink to open the document, I create a record in a log table like this:
[Log Entries Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i84MS.png).
What I want to do is show a form that will only display ECN entries that have not been viewed yet. This is the query that I am trying to come up that will show the ECN entries that have not been viewed.

SELECT ECNEntries.*
FROM ECNEntries, Logs
WHERE ******

So I have this query that will set a recorset based on 3 conditions:
1- User Name
2- Log Type
3- ECN Number

```
SELECT Logs.* FROM Logs WHERE (((Logs.LogType)="Open ECN") AND ((Logs.LogUser)="Denis Leclerc") AND ((Logs.LogNote)="20-121"))
```

How do I make the first query add the current record if the query count of the second query = 0 (meaning that the second query did not find that specific entry in the log table)? I don't know how the write the ******* section of the first query to make this work.

I will replace "20-121" with [ECNEntries]![ECNNumber] to made the have the ECN Number reflect the ECN number of the table being filtered. (Using Office 365,)

Thanks,  Denis

Comment: Are you trying to display all ECN entries that have *never* been viewed, or all ECN entries that have never been viewed *by this user*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like at its heart, you need to join Entries and Logs to find all the times Logs does **not** have a corresponding match for this entry + user. That is the definition of a LEFT JOIN.

```sql
SELECT ECNEntries.* 
FROM ECNEntries
LEFT JOIN Logs ON ECNEntries.ECNNumber = Logs.LogNote 
   AND Logs.LogType = 'Open ECN' -- is this needed? Are there times where LogNote has a value but it is not an Open or Close ECN?
   AND Logs.LogUser = 'Denis Leclerc'
WHERE Logs.ID IS NULL    -- show us all ECNEntries that fail to have a corresponding Logs Open row
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. That did it with a few mods.

1- Yes the "Open ECN" is needed because there will be other types of log that will be kept.
2- I will modify the user name in the string from the Log In form code once someone logs in.
3- I only need to change the single quote to double quote for text ('Denis Leclerc' to "Denis Leclerc") and add parentheses between AND commands.

Here is the sql string that worked.

```
SELECT ECNEntries.* FROM ECNEntries LEFT JOIN Logs ON ((ECNEntries.ECNNumber = Logs.LogNote) AND (Logs.LogType = "Open ECN") AND (Logs.LogUser = "Denis Leclerc")) WHERE (Logs.ID) Is Null
```

Again thank you very much. You guys are great.

Denis